# Capture Depth Image without opening Visualizer in Open3D?

Tags: python, performance, open3d

I'm looking to batch process 50,000+ 3D models. I need to capture depth maps from different angles. Using Open3D, How can I capture this information without launching the visualizer? In hopes of speeding up the process?

Comment: Hmm, can't help but can advise: search for issue similar to your case in [open3d github](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues). If there is nothing to be found, make new issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could check [Open3D OffScreen](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer.html)

It will render depth map or images without window, in other words, it can run batches in background.

Here are the example.

```
import copy
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_width, img_height = (1920, 1080)
pcd = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('bunny.ply')

mat = o3d.visualization.rendering.Material()
mat.shader = 'defaultUnlit'

renderer_pc = o3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer(img_width, img_height)
renderer_pc.scene.set_background(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0]))
renderer_pc.scene.add_geometry("pcd", pcd, mat)

# Optionally set the camera field of view (to zoom in a bit)
vertical_field_of_view = 15.0  # between 5 and 90 degrees
aspect_ratio = img_width / img_height  # azimuth over elevation
near_plane = 0.1
far_plane = 50.0
fov_type = o3d.visualization.rendering.Camera.FovType.Vertical
renderer_pc.scene.camera.set_projection(vertical_field_of_view, aspect_ratio, near_plane, far_plane, fov_type)

# Look at the origin from the front (along the -Z direction, into the screen), with Y as Up.
center = [0, 0, 0]  # look_at target
eye = [0, 0, 2]  # camera position
up = [0, 1, 0]  # camera orientation
renderer_pc.scene.camera.look_at(center, eye, up)

depth_image = np.asarray(renderer_pc.render_to_depth_image())
np.save('depth', depth_image)

normalized_image = (depth_image - depth_image.min()) / (depth_image.max() - depth_image.min())
plt.imshow(normalized_image)
plt.savefig('depth.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Windows 11 and I still get the error "EGL Headless is not supported on this platform"

Answer (score 1):

`o3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer` is not currently working in Open3D versions 0.16.0 and 0.17.0, but works on version 0.15.1. There's an open issue [here](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/5776).

An alternative would be to build Open3D headless: http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Advanced/headless_rendering.html